# Python dictionary - more optimal

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How could I make this code more optimal, not to have repetition?

```
for item in my_dict["environment"]:
    item.update({"service": service})
    item.update({"project_name": project})
    item.update({"arti_path": arti_path})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean:

```py
item.update({"service": service, "project_name": project, "arti_path": arti_path})
```